# How to read simultaneously by several COM ports

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, readfile

I have several weather stations to which there is no software that takes into account current of the battery in the console itself.
I found the code that reads the current console, but I want to read current of 8 consoles simultaneously.

For now connects over COM port and transfer rate data, then recorded current voltage console on TXT file.
How can I fix the code to read a few COM ports simultaneously ?

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Text;
using System.IO;


namespace ConsoleApplication1
{

        public class WeatherLoopData
    {
       /*
             private int barTrend = 0,
                    currWindSpeed = 0,
                    avgWindSpeed = 0,
                    insideHumidity = 0,
                    outsideHumidity = 0,
                    windDirection = 0;
       */
        private float voltage = 0;
        // private float voltage1 = 0;
        /*
        private bool transmitter = true;

        private float barometer = 0.0F,
                      insideTemp = 0.0F,
                      outsideTemp = 0.0F,
                      dayRain = 0.0F;
       */
        private DateTime sunRise = DateTime.Now,
                         sunSet = DateTime.Now;
        /*
        public int BarometricTrend { get { return barTrend; } }

        public int CurrentWindSpeed { get { return currWindSpeed; } }

        public int AvgWindSpeed { get { return avgWindSpeed; } }

        public int InsideHumidity { get { return insideHumidity; } }

        public int OutsideHumidity { get { return outsideHumidity; } }

        public float Barometer { get { return barometer; } }

        public float InsideTemperature { get { return insideTemp; } }

        public float OutsideTemperature { get { return outsideTemp; } }

        public float DailyRain { get { return dayRain; } }

        public int WindDirection
        {
            get { return windDirection; }

        }
        */

        public void Load(byte[] loopArray)
        {

            int hours,
               minutes;
            string timeString;
            DateTime currTime;
            /*
            barTrend = Convert.ToInt32((sbyte)loopArray[3]);                    // Sbyte - signed byte
            barometer = (float)(BitConverter.ToInt16(loopArray, 7)) / 1000;     // Uint16
            insideTemp = (float)(BitConverter.ToInt16(loopArray, 9)) / 10;      // Uint16
            insideHumidity = Convert.ToInt32(loopArray[11]);                    // Byte - unsigned byte
            outsideTemp = (float)(BitConverter.ToInt16(loopArray, 12)) / 10;    // Uint16
            outsideHumidity = Convert.ToInt32(loopArray[33]);                   // Byte - unsigned byte
            windDirection = BitConverter.ToInt16(loopArray, 16);                // Uint16
            currWindSpeed = Convert.ToInt32(loopArray[14]);                     // Byte - unsigned byte
            avgWindSpeed = Convert.ToInt32(loopArray[15]);                      // Byte - unsigned byte
            dayRain = (float)(BitConverter.ToInt16(loopArray, 50)) / 100;       // Uint16
            */
            voltage = (float)BitConverter.ToInt16(loopArray, 87) * 300 / 512 / 100;  //Тока на конзолата
            //voltage1 = (float)BitConverter.ToInt16(loopArray, 87) * 300 / 512 / 100; //Тока на конзолата
            //transmitter = BitConverter.ToBoolean(loopArray, 86); //Не показва тока на трансмитера



            // get the current date and time
            currTime = DateTime.Now;

            // Time from the Vatnage is all in 24-hour format.  I move it into a string so I can manipulate it 
            // more easily.
            timeString = BitConverter.ToInt16(loopArray, 91).ToString();    // Uint16
            // Exract hours and minutes and convert them to integers - required by Datetime
            hours = Convert.ToInt32(timeString.Substring(0, timeString.Length - 2));
            minutes = Convert.ToInt32(timeString.Substring(timeString.Length - 2, 2));
            // Create a new Datetime instance - use surrent year, month and day
            sunRise = new DateTime(currTime.Year, currTime.Month, currTime.Day, hours, minutes, 0);

            timeString = BitConverter.ToInt16(loopArray, 93).ToString();    // Uint16
            hours = Convert.ToInt32(timeString.Substring(0, timeString.Length - 2));
            minutes = Convert.ToInt32(timeString.Substring(timeString.Length - 2, 2));
            sunSet = new DateTime(currTime.Year, currTime.Month, currTime.Day, hours, minutes, 0);
        }



        public string DebugString()
        {

            StringBuilder outputString = new StringBuilder();
            /*
            Format the string for output
            outputString.Append("Barometer: " + barometer.ToString("f2") + "in. " + BarTrendText() + Environment.NewLine);
            outputString.Append("Inside Temp in F: " + insideTemp.ToString() + Environment.NewLine);
            outputString.Append("Inside Humidity: " + insideHumidity.ToString() + "%" + Environment.NewLine);
            outputString.Append("Outside Temp: " + outsideTemp.ToString() + Environment.NewLine);
            outputString.Append("Outside Humidity: " + outsideHumidity.ToString() + "%" + Environment.NewLine);
            outputString.Append("Wind Direction: " + WindDirectionText() + " @ " + windDirection.ToString() + " degrees" + Environment.NewLine);
            outputString.Append("Current Wind Speed: " + currWindSpeed.ToString() + "MPH" + Environment.NewLine);
            outputString.Append("10 Minute Average Wind Speed: " + avgWindSpeed.ToString() + "MPH" + Environment.NewLine);
            outputString.Append("Daily Rain: " + dayRain.ToString() + "in" + Environment.NewLine);
            outputString.Append("Sunrise: " + sunRise.ToString("t") + Environment.NewLine);
            outputString.Append("Sunset: " + sunSet.ToString("t") + Environment.NewLine);
            outputString.Append("Voltage: " + voltage.ToString() + Environment.NewLine);
            outputString.Append("Transmitter Voltage: " + transmitter.ToString() + Environment.NewLine); */
            File.WriteAllText(@"C:\Users\admin\Desktop\Voltage.txt", "№ станция" + " " + string.Format("{0:yyyy-MM-dd HH-mm}", DateTime.Now) + " " + Convert.ToString(voltage) + "V");
            //File.WriteAllText(@"C:\Users\admin\Desktop\Voltage1.txt", "№ станция" + " " + string.Format("{0:yyyy-MM-dd HH-mm}", DateTime.Now) + " " + Convert.ToString(voltage1) + "V");


            return (outputString.ToString());
        }

       /* private string BarTrendText()
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        } */

         /* private string WindDirectionText()
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        } */

        public float BatteryVoltage { get { return voltage; } }

        //public float BatteryVoltage1 { get { return voltage1; } }



        // public bool TransmitterVoltage { get { return transmitter; } }


        public DateTime SunRise { get { return sunRise; } }

        public DateTime SunSet { get { return sunSet; } }

        // Load - dissassembles the byte array passed in and loads it into local data that the accessors can use.
        // Actual data is in the format to the right of the assignments - I convert it to make it easier to use
        // When bytes have to be assembled into 2-byte, 16-bit numbers, I convert two bytes from the array into 
        // an Int16 (16-bit integer).  When a single byte is all that's needed, I just convert it to an Int32.
        // In the end, all integers are cast to Int32 for return.


        }
    }



  using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Text;
using System.IO;


namespace ConsoleApplication1
{

        public class WeatherLoopData
    {
       /*
             private int barTrend = 0,
                    currWindSpeed = 0,
                    avgWindSpeed = 0,
                    insideHumidity = 0,
                    outsideHumidity = 0,
                    windDirection = 0;
       */
        private float voltage = 0;
        // private float voltage1 = 0;
        /*
        private bool transmitter = true;

        private float barometer = 0.0F,
                      insideTemp = 0.0F,
                      outsideTemp = 0.0F,
                      dayRain = 0.0F;
       */
        private DateTime sunRise = DateTime.Now,
                         sunSet = DateTime.Now;
        /*
        public int BarometricTrend { get { return barTrend; } }

        public int CurrentWindSpeed { get { return currWindSpeed; } }

        public int AvgWindSpeed { get { return avgWindSpeed; } }

        public int InsideHumidity { get { return insideHumidity; } }

        public int OutsideHumidity { get { return outsideHumidity; } }

        public float Barometer { get { return barometer; } }

        public float InsideTemperature { get { return insideTemp; } }

        public float OutsideTemperature { get { return outsideTemp; } }

        public float DailyRain { get { return dayRain; } }

        public int WindDirection
        {
            get { return windDirection; }

        }
        */

        public void Load(byte[] loopArray)
        {

            int hours,
               minutes;
            string timeString;
            DateTime currTime;
            /*
            barTrend = Convert.ToInt32((sbyte)loopArray[3]);                    // Sbyte - signed byte
            barometer = (float)(BitConverter.ToInt16(loopArray, 7)) / 1000;     // Uint16
            insideTemp = (float)(BitConverter.ToInt16(loopArray, 9)) / 10;      // Uint16
            insideHumidity = Convert.ToInt32(loopArray[11]);                    // Byte - unsigned byte
            outsideTemp = (float)(BitConverter.ToInt16(loopArray, 12)) / 10;    // Uint16
            outsideHumidity = Convert.ToInt32(loopArray[33]);                   // Byte - unsigned byte
            windDirection = BitConverter.ToInt16(loopArray, 16);                // Uint16
            currWindSpeed = Convert.ToInt32(loopArray[14]);                     // Byte - unsigned byte
            avgWindSpeed = Convert.ToInt32(loopArray[15]);                      // Byte - unsigned byte
            dayRain = (float)(BitConverter.ToInt16(loopArray, 50)) / 100;       // Uint16
            */
            voltage = (float)BitConverter.ToInt16(loopArray, 87) * 300 / 512 / 100;  //Тока на конзолата
            //voltage1 = (float)BitConverter.ToInt16(loopArray, 87) * 300 / 512 / 100; //Тока на конзолата
            //transmitter = BitConverter.ToBoolean(loopArray, 86); //Не показва тока на трансмитера



            // get the current date and time
            currTime = DateTime.Now;

            // Time from the Vatnage is all in 24-hour format.  I move it into a string so I can manipulate it 
            // more easily.
            timeString = BitConverter.ToInt16(loopArray, 91).ToString();    // Uint16
            // Exract hours and minutes and convert them to integers - required by Datetime
            hours = Convert.ToInt32(timeString.Substring(0, timeString.Length - 2));
            minutes = Convert.ToInt32(timeString.Substring(timeString.Length - 2, 2));
            // Create a new Datetime instance - use surrent year, month and day
            sunRise = new DateTime(currTime.Year, currTime.Month, currTime.Day, hours, minutes, 0);

            timeString = BitConverter.ToInt16(loopArray, 93).ToString();    // Uint16
            hours = Convert.ToInt32(timeString.Substring(0, timeString.Length - 2));
            minutes = Convert.ToInt32(timeString.Substring(timeString.Length - 2, 2));
            sunSet = new DateTime(currTime.Year, currTime.Month, currTime.Day, hours, minutes, 0);
        }



        public string DebugString()
        {

            StringBuilder outputString = new StringBuilder();
            /*
            Format the string for output
            outputString.Append("Barometer: " + barometer.ToString("f2") + "in. " + BarTrendText() + Environment.NewLine);
            outputString.Append("Inside Temp in F: " + insideTemp.ToString() + Environment.NewLine);
            outputString.Append("Inside Humidity: " + insideHumidity.ToString() + "%" + Environment.NewLine);
            outputString.Append("Outside Temp: " + outsideTemp.ToString() + Environment.NewLine);
            outputString.Append("Outside Humidity: " + outsideHumidity.ToString() + "%" + Environment.NewLine);
            outputString.Append("Wind Direction: " + WindDirectionText() + " @ " + windDirection.ToString() + " degrees" + Environment.NewLine);
            outputString.Append("Current Wind Speed: " + currWindSpeed.ToString() + "MPH" + Environment.NewLine);
            outputString.Append("10 Minute Average Wind Speed: " + avgWindSpeed.ToString() + "MPH" + Environment.NewLine);
            outputString.Append("Daily Rain: " + dayRain.ToString() + "in" + Environment.NewLine);
            outputString.Append("Sunrise: " + sunRise.ToString("t") + Environment.NewLine);
            outputString.Append("Sunset: " + sunSet.ToString("t") + Environment.NewLine);
            outputString.Append("Voltage: " + voltage.ToString() + Environment.NewLine);
            outputString.Append("Transmitter Voltage: " + transmitter.ToString() + Environment.NewLine); */
            File.WriteAllText(@"C:\Users\admin\Desktop\Voltage.txt", "№ станция" + " " + string.Format("{0:yyyy-MM-dd HH-mm}", DateTime.Now) + " " + Convert.ToString(voltage) + "V");
            //File.WriteAllText(@"C:\Users\admin\Desktop\Voltage1.txt", "№ станция" + " " + string.Format("{0:yyyy-MM-dd HH-mm}", DateTime.Now) + " " + Convert.ToString(voltage1) + "V");


            return (outputString.ToString());
        }

       /* private string BarTrendText()
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        } */

         /* private string WindDirectionText()
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        } */

        public float BatteryVoltage { get { return voltage; } }

        //public float BatteryVoltage1 { get { return voltage1; } }



        // public bool TransmitterVoltage { get { return transmitter; } }


        public DateTime SunRise { get { return sunRise; } }

        public DateTime SunSet { get { return sunSet; } }

        // Load - dissassembles the byte array passed in and loads it into local data that the accessors can use.
        // Actual data is in the format to the right of the assignments - I convert it to make it easier to use
        // When bytes have to be assembled into 2-byte, 16-bit numbers, I convert two bytes from the array into 
        // an Int16 (16-bit integer).  When a single byte is all that's needed, I just convert it to an Int32.
        // In the end, all integers are cast to Int32 for return.


        }
    }
```

Comment: You can use a separate thread per COM port.

Comment: Can you show me how, please ?

Comment: That's a bit too large a topic to answer here... You'll have to learn about multithreading somehow. [This might get you started.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2605966/how-to-create-multiple-threads-in-c-sharp)

Answer (score 0):

I would make a class for each station and then have a list of stations something like code below

```
    class Program
    {
        const int NUMBER_PORTS = 5;
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            for(int i = 0; i < NUMBER_PORTS; i++)
            {
                WeatherLoopData newStation = new WeatherLoopData("Com" + (i + 1).ToString());
                WeatherLoopData.ports.Add(newStation);
            }


        }
        public class WeatherLoopData
        {
            public static List<WeatherLoopData> ports = new List<WeatherLoopData>();
            SerialPort port = null;
            public WeatherLoopData(string portName)
            {
                port = new SerialPort(portName);
            }
            //enter your code here

        }
```