# Tracking concurrent object access for an IDisposable

Tags: c#, multithreading

I have an `IDisposable` object that can be accessed between multiple threads. I am trying to figure out a way to track that the object is "in use" before performing any clean up. In other words, I need to keep some sort of reference count to indicate that there are running methods (which are decremented when they complete) so that the Dispose method wouldn't continue until they are all complete (or after some timeout has passed). But I also need to make sure that once `Dispose` has been entered that any future calls to `Method` fail.

Something like:

```
class MyObject : IDisposable
{
    private long _counter;
    private bool _stopping;
    private IDisposable _someResource;
    public void Method()
    {
        if (_stopping)
            throw new InvalidOperationException();

        Interlocked.Increment(ref _counter);
        try
        {
            // do some work             
        }
        finally
        {
            Interlocked.Decrement(ref _counter);
        }
    }

    public void Dispose()
    {
        var timeout = DateTime.Now.Add(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(15));
        while ( DateTime.Now < timeout && Volatile.Read(ref _counter) > 0)
        {
            // wait
            // Thread.Sleep(10) or something
        }

        _stopping = true;
        //perform clean up
        _someResource.Dispose();        
    }
}
```

However this won't work because `Method()` may be called again and `_stopping` hasn't been set but the `Dispose` would continue, invalidating everything else.

Is there a specific pattern that I can use here or perhaps some framework classes that can be used to solve this? Basically some two-way signal telling `Dispose` that nothing is in process so its good-to-go while signalling `Method` that it should fail.

I found [CountdownEvent](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.countdownevent(v=vs.110).aspx) but I'm not sure how I can use it here. [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2357330/491907) shows an example `CountdownLatch` but it doesn't prevent new work from being requested.

Comment: Why would you make your *object* responsible for this, and not your *clients*? If they need safe concurrent access, let them lock, like the rest of the world does. Although a thread-safe `Dispose` is useful, this can be achieved with a simple `Interlocked.CompareExchange`. Making the disposing thread-safe with regards to *other* operations is unusual. The usual approach is to signal the object as unavailable for any *future* operation from the moment `Dispose` is called, and not try to get fancy with any work still in progress.

Comment: "[...]`_stopping` hasn't been set[...]" Why don't you assign it a value before your waiting loop ?

Comment: Thought about setting it at the start after I wrote the above but figured it'd fall into the same trap. As to why? Because I inherited it like this and I'm trying to see what I can do to fix it.

Comment: Well, if you can't make your clients lock, you can still trivially do it yourself. Mutual exclusion will solve most any threading problem, and this one's no exception. Doing it safely will get messy, though. Is `Method` already thread safe somehow or is that another accident waiting to happen?

Comment: `Method` itself is already thread safe.

Comment: When you start reference-counting then you are well beyond what's reasonable to make IDisposable work.  Time to take advantage of the contract, calling Dispose() is *optional*.  Don't panic.

Answer (score 0):

No. Just say no to the Dispose method being responsible for "tracking" all instances consuming the class. The consumers of the class need to handle their clean-up and properly dispose.

If Dispose can be called multiple times by multiple classes, then you've just found a code smell. Only one class should being calling the dispose method; and that class should be tracking the consumers of the class with the Dispose method.

A common pattern for preventing dispose from being called multiple times is to set up a flag, similar to what you have now. Use the [ObjectDisposedException](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.objectdisposedexception(v=vs.110).aspx) as needed:

```
private bool _zombified;

public void Method()
{
    if (_zombified)
        throw new ObjectDisposedException();

    // method's logic
}


public void Dispose
{
    if(_zombified)
    {
        return;
    }

    _zombified = true;

    // perform clean-up
}
```

Comment: One class is responsible for calling dispose, but it's unfortunately passed to other classes that invoke the method on it (yet don't dispose) . I inherited this and I'm fully aware that it is ugly.

Comment: Is there anything preventing the other code/classes from being modified to remove the dispose call(s)?

Comment: Not sure I follow your question