# Killing all threads that opened by application

Tags: c#, .net, j#

I have some really big application mixture of c# and j#.

Sometimes when  I close it, there are some threads that are not closed and they are hanging in the task manager and it is impossible to kill them from there.

I have really problem to find all those threads and add them to the closing event .

Is there some way  violently kill all threads that were opened by application in the closing event ?...

Thanks.

Is there maybe some Tool that can tell me what threads are opened while i close the application and who openned them ?

Comment: Also see: [Shutting down a multithreaded application](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2314861/shutting-down-a-multithreaded-application)

Answer (score 54, accepted):

This *shouldn't be happening*, and if it is, you're trying to address it the wrong way.

When your application exits, the .NET Framework will automatically kill any threads whose [`IsBackground` property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.thread.isbackground.aspx) is set to "True". Designate each of your worker threads as background threads, and you won't have this problem anymore. Taking advantage of the [`BackgroundWorker` class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.backgroundworker.aspx) and the [`ThreadPool` class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.threadpool.aspx), which automatically create background threads, is a much better option.

Otherwise, you need to clean up your foreground threads explicitly. A properly designed application will do its own bookkeeping and have a deterministic, structured way of ensuring that all its threads have been closed before exiting the `Main` method. This is what you should be doing *anyway* if your threads require a graceful termination.

Killing the process is a very bad idea, as is letting your threads run about willy-nilly in your application.

Comment: Well yes this is the nice explanation.... But what if you call a WCF web service from a thread where the service is stuck in some undefined state. You can't wait endlessly. You must kill that thread. There is no other way or I am wrong ?

Comment: You don't kill the thread, you call the web service with a timeout. @patrik

Answer (score 18):

You can use : Environment.Exit(0); , that will shutdown the application if threads are running and wont cause any problems.

Comment: this worked along with setting `IsBackground` property of thread is set to `True`

Answer (score 9):

You should close your threads gracefully, but just want you and others to know the way that is not recommended but possible:

on your OnClose Handler:

```
System.Diagnostics.Process.GetCurrentProcess().Kill();
```

I totally prefer Cody Gray way of doing it.

Comment: Yes it works, especially if you use background thread and try to close all with Environment.Exit(0)

Comment: Great, I have a complicated thread running and found no logic to stop it before exit.   Your code killed it and no more instances running in the background, Thank you

Answer (score 4):

Well, you could call `Application.Exit()` but that won't be of much help. 
The bottom line is that you have to gracefully close all of the threads yourself if you want to do things properly.

Comment: Didn't work. I think you meant `Environment.Exit()` like in the other answer, that works.

Answer (score 1):

My 2 cents... to all answers...

Try to force SHUTDOWN

Put into `void CurrentApplication_Exit(object sender, ExitEventArgs e)` and `private void Window_Closing(object sender, CancelEventArgs e)` those lines

```
System.Windows.Application.Current.ShutdownMode = ShutdownMode.OnExplicitShutdown;
System.Windows.Application.Current.Shutdown();
```

Answer (score 0):

```
internal void Close()
{
    Dispatcher.CurrentDispatcher.Thread.Abort();
    Application.Current.ShutdownMode = ShutdownMode.OnExplicitShutdown;
    Application.Current.Shutdown();
}
```

Comment: but it looks better Environment.Exit(0);

Comment: The answer will be more helpful if you add a description to the block of code.

Comment: This is specific to wpf if I'm not mistaken

Answer (score 0):

I was having similar issue while closing form/application. It was not really exiting from the debug mode and comes to the design mode. Following resolves my issue.

1. Followed the link. 
   [Windows Form Application, Thread won't stop](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12894503/windows-form-application-thread-wont-stop)
2. Step one did not resolved it. 
    Environment.Exit(0);     -   Resolves and worked fine.

Comment: Please provide context from link because link may expire in future.