# How to kill all child threads in C#?

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading, winforms

Suppose, I have a server application. This application polls for incoming clients in a separate child thread. Also, sub-threads are spawned for each of the incoming clients to service their requests separately.

I want to kill all threads except the Server application's main thread, say, by clicking a button.

How can I do that?

Comment: By creating the threads properly or not at all - tasks are far easier to use. Background threads will be aborted when the main thread exits. In all cases it's *far better* to signal termination gracefully than abort an operation and leave garbage behind

Comment: duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12894503/windows-form-application-thread-wont-stop

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Windows Form Application, Thread won't stop](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12894503/windows-form-application-thread-wont-stop)

Comment: Be aware of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1559255/whats-wrong-with-using-thread-abort

Comment: Why are you asking? I suspect you created a lot of foreground threads and can't shut them down now? You can simplify your code a lot by using high-level constructs like asynchronous programming, tasks, channels or dataflow blocks instead of raw threads

Comment: I agree with the others: if you need to kill your own threads your design is fundamentally wrong.

Answer (score 1):

> This application polls for incoming clients in a separate child thread.

Okay, so it seems you are the one creating those threads. Can't you just keep a list of threads and then call `Abort` on them all? That seems the most straight-forward approach. (But be aware of some [caveats](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1560567/993547))

If that is not possible, you could get a list of [all threads](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10315862/993547), filter them on their name or some other characteristic, and `Abort` those.

A better approach is to use tasks, which are far better manageable than threads. You might want to read up on TPL.