# Why my timer wont work? C# i want to start Thread on pressing a key and to stops automatically

Tags: c#, if-statement, while-loop

Can someone tell me why this do not work?
i want to start a Thread by pressing a key and stops automatically, then he have to make a rest and starts again.
But if i pressing this key then nothing happens.
he have to start void StartFunction, but Thread isnt starting. If i start the Thread on Forms_load then is all fine. but i need this Thread only on pressing a key

```
private void StartFunction()
{
    Thread AB = new Thread(SEARCHING) { IsBackground = true };
    AB.Start();

}
private void StopFunction()
{
    Thread AB = new Thread(SEARCHING) { IsBackground = true };
    AB.Abort();

}
private void Form1_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.KeyCode == Keys.L)
    {
        StartFunction();
        MessageBox.Show("Timer 1 started!");

    }
}
int time = 10;
private void timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    
    time++;
    if (time == 2 && timer1.Enabled)
    {
        timer1.Stop();
        time = 0;
        StopFunction();


    }
    if (time == 2 && !timer1.Enabled)
    {
        timer1.Start();
        time = 0;
        StartFunction();
        MessageBox.Show("Timer 1 started!");
    }
}
```

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/it-it/dotnet/api/system.timers.timer.elapsed?view=net-6.0 Look this: the event Timer.Elapsed is generate when a certain time is elapsed. When this event is generated you can break the function.

Comment: your code will never do anything. 'time is set to 10 and the only code that decrements it depends on 'time == 0'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could make it easier for yourself by storing the timer_tick in a variable.
When the variable has reached 120(2 min) stop the timer. First you should start the timer and then:

```
    private void timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
       time++;
       if(time == 120 && timer1.Enabled)
       {
         timer1.Stop();
         time = 0;
       }
       if(time == 60 && !timer1.Enabled){
          timer1.Start();
          time = 0;
         }
    }
```

You can find the timer_tick event at the ptoperties of the timer.

Comment: time has a red underline ? What i have to set above?

Comment: ye sounds good but what kind of variable did i need for this.? i cannot start this code. "time" is red underlined

Comment: declare time above your constructor just like this: int time = 0.

Comment: can you please take a look on my Edited post? is this all correct? :)

Comment: I see that you have set the initial value of time to 10, thereafter you are checking if time == 2 while during every tick time gets +1. The condition will never be true. You have to increase the value of time in the if-statements to a value larger than its initial value.

Comment: ok nice that helps me very well, did you have any idea how to abort or kill a Thread from a other function ? i want to kill this Thread after timer is stopped. or maybe how can i let him stop normaly after time is over? after that i have no questions more :P Thanks guy :)

Comment: Check these links out. This might help.
[link]http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12894503/windows-form-application-thread-wont-stop[^]

[link2](Killing all threads that opened by application[^])