# How to shut down externally started threads by PrincipalContext?

Tags: c#, active-directory

```
using System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement;
[TestMethod]
public void TestPrincipalContext()
{
   using (new PrincipalContext(ContextType.Domain, "domain.com")){}
}
```

When running this code after the using completes there is a new thread running `System.DirectoryServices.Protocols.PartialResultsRetriever.ThreadRoutine` since I did not explicitly start the thread I have no handle to abort it.  Is there a way to get the thread to stop?

Comment: Try looking here :) http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5002279/killing-all-threads-that-opened-by-application